# Setting Tag of Objects added on view controller programmatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, core-data, uitapgesturerecognizer

Okay,Here is the issue which is literally out of mind. I have a view controller on which I have added `UITapGestureRecognizer`. When user taps on View,a custom UIView gets added on that tapped location. Here is the code for `UITapGestureRecogniser` :

```
 -(IBAction)singleTap_Detected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
 {
     CGPoint tapPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
     customView=[CustomPointUIView addCustomView];

     [customView.pointSelectionButton addTarget:self action:@selector(addInfoAction:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

     [self.view addSubview:customView];
     customView.layer.position=CGPointMake(tapPoint.x,tapPoint.y);

     [customViewsArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithCGPoint:tapPoint]];

     NSManagedObjectContext *context = [self.circuit managedObjectContext];

     // if there isn't an Point object, create and configure one
     self.point = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"PointDetail"
                                                                inManagedObjectContext:context];
     [self.circuit addPointObject:self.point];

     NSString *pointPosition=NSStringFromCGPoint(tapPoint);

     self.point.position=pointPosition;

     NSError *error = nil;
     if (![context save:&error])
     {
         NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
         abort();
     }
}
```

I am also saving the tapped location in `Core Data`. Now the problem is that I am unable to set the tag for each custom `UIView` added on View controller. As shown,every custom `UIView` has a button.On click of that `Button`,view is navigating to another view. Now I need to set the tag for every view. How is it possible ? I don't know I am able to clear my concept or not But I will be thankful from the depth of my heart.So,Please provide me a solution.I am new to iPhone.

Comment: Isn't it just `customView.tag = tagValue;`?

Comment: @Droppy Yes,but what should be the tagValue.I need it to be incremented with every new added `CustomView`

Comment: So, you have to add ivar `NSInteger tagValue` in your class and increment it every time after `customView.tag = tagValue; tagValue++`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to store the *next tag value* as an instance variable of this class:

```
@interface YourClass ()
{
    NSInteger _nextTagValue;
}
```

Ensure it's initialised to your starting value in `viewDidLoad` (or somewhere equivalent):

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    _nextTagValue = 100;
    ...
}
```

and use it like this:

```
-(IBAction)singleTap_Detected:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)recognizer
{
    CGPoint tapPoint = [recognizer locationInView:self.view];
    customView=[CustomPointUIView addCustomView];
    customView.tag = _nextTagValue++;

    ...
}
```

However it's unclear to me what this tag value *means* and how you want to use it and track it.  Please add detail if you require help with this.